# Unable to remotely access lightning-charge

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, core-lightning

My setup is a little bit complicated and I'm almost sure that my problem is port related.

So I'm running Mac OS X 10.13.4 with Parallels Desktop with a Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I managed to **setup bitcoin core** in the VM, on top of it I installed **c-lightning** and managed to fund it with btc (All is happening on the **testnet**) which I used to **open one channel** with some random other node. Everything is perfect for now.

Because I want to use the LApp for WordPress Lightning-Publisher I Installed **lightning-charge** and started an HTTP server running on the default port 9112. All of my ports are correctly forwarded and in my bitcoin.conf file I have allowed all ips. If I run Mozilla in my Ubuntu VM and go to `http://api-token:mySecretToken@localhost:9112/info` everything is fine, but when I try this on my Mac I get `Can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection`. If I try using my external ip it's the same thing.

Using several sites to check if my ports are correctly forwarded I get that all corresponding ports are open (18332 for BTC core, 9735 for c-lightning and 9112 for lightning-charge).

Here is my bitcoin.conf

```
testnet=1
server=1
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=someuser
rpcpassword=somepass

addnode=104.237.131.138
addnode=151.80.205.132
addnode=192.155.82.123
addnode=74.220.255.190
addnode=80.100.203.151
```

here is my lightning config

```
network=testnet
alias=IVCHOBIVCHO
port=9735
rgb=008000
```

Proof that 9112 is open:
[image: port open]

Proof that lightning-charge opens from inside the VM:
[image: inside VM]

And in Safari on my mac (using localhost:9112 returns the same error):
[image: in safari]

Neither Ubuntu, nor my Mac are under any kind of Firewall. My router is TP-Link

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of research I found the solution to my problem.

I didn't know this, but in nodejs there's a huge difference if your server runs on `127.0.0.1` and on `0.0.0.0`.

It isn't said in the lightning-charge docs, but except the **--port** attribute you also have **--host** which you can set.

Starting **lightning-charge** with this line `charged --api-token mySecretToken --host 0.0.0.0` fixed all of my problems. Gosh was that an unpleasant journey!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address (also known as localhost). ... If a host has two ip addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs.